# ReactJS: Sort Array

Tags: reactjs

I have a select as following:

```
  const categorizedDataMeals = awawameals.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const { CategoryValue, id, Category, Name, Foods } = curr;
    if (!acc[Category]) {
      acc[Category] = {
        items: [],
      };
    }
    acc[Category].items.push({ CategoryValue, Category, id, Name, Foods });
    return acc;
  }, {});
```

This sorts it by Category, and returns the following array:

```
{
    DINNER: {
        items: [
            {
                CategoryValue: '3dinner',
                Category: 'DINNER',
                id: 'LyuZjWxFs26HGO8UMoSU',
                Name: 'Chicken Curry - Green',
            },
        ],
    },
    BREAKFAST: {
        items: [
            {
                CategoryValue: '1breakfast',
                Category: 'BREAKFAST',
                id: 'AJQUCL6x2zT8qylQsGPr',
                Name: 'Omelette ',
            },
        ],
    },
    LUNCH: {
        items: [
            {
                CategoryValue: '2lunch',
                Category: 'LUNCH',
                id: 'ukZv9L19IHwIk4QRs0Aq',
                Name: 'Wraps - Ham & Salad',
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

I want to keep the array the same, but I want to sort by CategoryValue (so that it shows breakfast then lunch then dinner)

I am using this to display:

```
{ Object.keys(categorizedDataMeals).sort().map((key, index) => {
return ( <><div style={{ clear: 'both', height: '20px' }}></div>
<h3>{key}</h3> } ) }
```

If I replace the acc[Category] with acc[CategoryValue] it sorts, but then the key shows this value.

How do I return acc so that it is sorted by CategoryValue?

Comment: What exactly is the sorting criteria? Just this very order: `Breakfast`->`Lunch`->`Dinner`? Besides, what you showed in your question is not an array but an object.

Comment: Yes, I want it sorted by Breakfast -> Lunch -> Dinner ... categoryvalue I have prepended it to have 1, 2 and 3 for sorting purposes.

Comment: Are you trying to sort the object keys or the `items` property array by `CategoryValue` assuming there might be more than 1 item?

Comment: Object keys - current that is how I want to display then (using Category) but I simply want that object sorted by CategoryValue

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to sort the properties of your object by the number prefix of the `CategoryValue` of the `items` array you can use `Object.entries()` and sort the Object keys like this:

```js
const data = {
  DINNER: {
    items: [{
      CategoryValue: '3dinner',
      Category: 'DINNER',
      id: 'LyuZjWxFs26HGO8UMoSU',
      Name: 'Chicken Curry - Green',
    }, ],
  },
  BREAKFAST: {
    items: [{
      CategoryValue: '1breakfast',
      Category: 'BREAKFAST',
      id: 'AJQUCL6x2zT8qylQsGPr',
      Name: 'Omelette ',
    }, ],
  },
  LUNCH: {
    items: [{
      CategoryValue: '2lunch',
      Category: 'LUNCH',
      id: 'ukZv9L19IHwIk4QRs0Aq',
      Name: 'Wraps - Ham & Salad',
    }, ],
  },
};

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).sort(
  ([, a], [, b]) => +a.items[0].CategoryValue.substring(0, 1) - +b.items[0].CategoryValue.substring(0, 1)
));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Looks good, but that returns a different structure ( with the two [ )

Comment: You're right! I updated my answer.

Comment: OK, it looks correct - but still showing the object as [link]https://freeimage.host/i/NwcIsa

Comment: What do you mean? They way the console displays output depends on the browser not the code. Also why can `items` suddenly contain more than only one item?

Comment: items can have multiple within it. also I gave you the screenshot as it is still not sorting via Breakfast, Lunch, Dinner. Still sorting as Breakfast, Dinner, Lunch

Comment: At this point I'm asking for the fifth time or so what you want. Please just specify your requirements. Tell us what is your input and what is your expected output. Obviously people aren't understanding since nobody posts an answer.